# Change architecture of module to correctly handle transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, architecture, transactions

I have application with modular architecture. Each module in this application communicate between each other though RPC protocol. This application is built on top of custom framework which is based on spring and hibernate inside. Each module has three layers architecture inside, so there is application layer in order to expose API for different modules or for UI part, it also has service layer in order to define business logic and handle transactions, data access layer in order to access/manage db data. 
Additionally each module of this application is deployed as separate service (WAR) on dedicated port of application server. Also, each module has their own db connection pool. Currently we are working on performance topic and there is following scenario where performance should be improved:

```
Given: Module1.Component1 marked as @Transactional
And: Component1.method1() makes call to Module2.Component1
And: Module2.Component1 responds in 
  1sec;
  30sec;
  1min; 
  not responding;
  responds with exception.

There are the following load on Module1Componet1
  1 request/sec
  10 requests/sec
```

With high load on the Module1 and with slow response of Module2 both jdbc connection pool are full and both modules are unable to react on further requests.

As an idea to improve performance for Module1, following changes can take place:

```
Extract external call to another module out of open transaction for Module1
```

It will fix performance issue and Module1 will behave appropriately even if Module2 response will be too slow and there will be huge bunch of request on Module1. This fix can be done on service layer with movement of @Transaction annotation to another place to do external call out of transaction. But, question is how to do this correctly in order to avoid similar issues in the future when developers will do similar changes. Could you please advice how it can be possible to restrict this though architecture, namely how to force to call RPC remote calls out of db transaction for future development?

Comment: That might be hard to answer without knowing more details - which in turn might be too much for SO. Right off the top of my head I could think of 2 things: 1) try to intercept the remote calls and check for active transactions - if one is found throw an exception. The devs should become aware of this during their tests at the latest. 2) A different approach to your architecture might be what you need, e.g. some form of non-blocking/asynchronous/event-based architecture like Vert.x is providing.

Comment: Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/637853/thomas, I got your point! First of all, I'll try to go with option 1. Additionally, I try to play with architecture test https://www.archunit.org/ in order to prevent such things during development.